# How do I insert the middle initial to my macro in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the initials from the first, middle,last name from specific these specific cells but my formula for variable a is not working. Any ideas?
ex. John Smith Doe --> J.S.D.
I was able to get J.D. but I'm having a hard time with the middle name

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim first As String
Dim last As String
Dim initial As String
first = Range("C2").Value
middle = Range("C3").Value
last = Range("C4").Value

    
c = first & " " & last

Range("C8").Value = c

Full = first & " " & middle & " " & last

a = Left(Full, 1) & "." & Mid$(Full, InStr(Full, " ") + 1, 1) & "." & Right(Full, InStr(Full, " ")) & "."


Range("C6").Value = a


b = last & ", " & first & "," & a

Range("C7").Value = b

End Sub
```

Comment: `Left(first, 1) & "." & Left(middle, 1) & "." & Left(last, 1) & "."`

Comment: ^^^Use the original already split values, no need to parse a string you concatenated.

Comment: What do you mean by `is not working` - what is the result and what were you expecting? Any error messages? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's a button assigned to a macro so no results, no error messages

Comment: That worked for me, I was doing that incase there was no middle name assigned

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better way....

```
Public Sub Test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Place the results of the FirstLetters function into cell C7.
        'Range C2:C4 on Sheet1 is passed to the function where it's called Target.
        .Range("C7") = FirstLetters(.Range("C2:C4"))
    End With
End Sub

'Target is a reference to Range C2:C4 on Sheet1.
Public Function FirstLetters(Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Tmp As String
    
    'Look at each cell in Target and grab the first character.
    'Stick it on the end of the Tmp string and add a space.
    For Each Cell In Target
        Tmp = Tmp & Left(Cell, 1) & " "
    Next Cell
    
    'Trim the last space off and return the results to the calling procedure.
    FirstLetters = Trim(Tmp)
End Function
```